# MethodInfo.Invoke with out Parameter

Tags: c#

an example code what I try to do will surely do better than my english:

```
public bool IsNumericValueInBounds (string value, Type numericType)
{
  double d = double.NaN;     

  bool inBounds = (bool)numericType.GetMethod ("TryParse").Invoke (null, new object[] { value, d });

  return inBounds;
}
```

Unfortunately the TryParse method needs an out parameter so this doesn't work.
any ideas how to solve this?

(ps.: would'nt this be a nice example for duck typing? - because i know every numericType has an "TryParse" or I am mistaken?)

Comment: You should be able to parse any numeric type to double, so double.TryParse() should do it here?

Comment: For people coming here in the future: @Lars, not every numeric can be parsed to double without losing precision, `decimal` in particular is the worst offender here.

Comment: .NET Framework has built-in functionality for IConvertible type conversions:
[TypeConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter(v=vs.110).aspx), [GetConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.getconverter(v=vs.110).aspx), [Convert.ChangeType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype(v=vs.110).aspx), [Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010669/typeconverter-vs-convert-vs-targettype-parse)

Answer (score 164, accepted):

```
public static bool TryParse( string text, out int number ) { .. }

MethodInfo method = GetTryParseMethodInfo();
object[] parameters = new object[]{ "12345", null }
object result = method.Invoke( null, parameters );
bool blResult = (bool)result;
if ( blResult ) {
    int parsedNumber = (int)parameters[1];
}
```

Comment: In case anyone is wondering why this works, the array of parameters is an object array and the null object at index 1 is replaced by the out parameter value.   If you put a variable in the array (e.g., new object[] { "123", myVar };) then after Invoke the value of myVar will not change but parameters[1] will still contain the out parameter value.