# TypeConverter vs. Convert vs. TargetType.Parse

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

As far as I know, there are at least 3 ways to convert data types in .NET:

---

using [System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx)

```
var conv = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(int));
var i1 = (int)conv.ConvertFrom("123");
```

using [System.Convert.ChangeType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cytax8kf.aspx):

```
var i2 = (int) Convert.ChangeType("123", typeof (int));
```

using the [Parse/TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx) methods of the destination type:

```
var i3 = int.Parse("123"); // or TryParse
```

---

Are there any guidelines or rules-of-thumb **when to use which method** to convert between the .NET base data types (especially from string to some other data type)?

Comment: Oh and don't forget about `System.ComponentModel.NullableConverter`. `System.Convert` can not handle nullable types (convert `string "123"` to type `int?`), and instead of building it into the existing converter(s), they just made yet another :)

Comment: Convert.ChangeType uses int.Parse() so no difference there.  A TypeConverter uses Reflection, best avoided if you care about perf.

Comment: @Hans: why not post it as an answer? seems to be a valuable piece of information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm going to post here 6 years late, because I think this is a good question and I am not satisfied with the existing answers.

The static `Parse/TryParse` methods can be used only **when you want to convert from string to the type** that has those methods. (use `TryParse` when you expect that the conversion may fail).

The point of `System.Convert` is, as its [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says, to convert **from a base data type to another base data type**. Note that with Convert you also have methods that take an `Object` and figure out by themselves how to convert it.

As to `System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter`, as the "typeconverter" stack overflow tag's [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/typeconverter/info), they are used primarily to convert **to and from string**, when you want to **provide a text representation** of a class instance for use by **designer serialization** or for **display in property grids**

Answer (score 6):

#### Convert

[Convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.convert) class uses the [IConvertible](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.iconvertible) methods implemented in the target type.

Unfortunately, implementing `IConvertible` means writing lots of boilerplate code and [Convert.ChangeType](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype) causes boxing if the target type is a struct.

#### TypeConverterAttribute

[TypeDescriptor.GetConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.getconverter) uses the [TypeConverterAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute) and IMHO offers both a better API to convert a type and a more elegant way to make a type convertible. But it suffers the same performance issues with the `Convert` class, caused by the methods not being generic.

#### Parse/TryParse

Using `T.Parse`/`T.TryParse` methods is the de facto way of creating an object from a string since it doesn't involve unnecessary boxing. They also usually have overloads that provide greater control of how to parse the string.

`TryParse` methods allow you to handle cases where the string you want to parse is obtained from user input or another mean that doesn't guarantee a properly formatted string, without throwing exceptions.

---

So you should call the type's `Parse`/`TryParse` methods *when you can* and fallback to the other ways only when you don't know the target type in the compile time, i.e. when you only have a [Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.type) object that represents your target type.

You can also have look at my little library called [ValueString](https://github.com/safakgur/value-string) that finds the most suitable parsing method of a type and uses it to parse the string.

Answer (score 4):

According to my personal preference and coding standards I choose between the following:

1. `Convert`. I use this when I am absolutely sure that the values will be what I expect.

   ```
   int i = Convert.ToInt32("123");
   ```
2. `TryParse`. I use this when I am handling user input. This also has the benefit to be able to use localized formatting when parsing.

   ```
   int i = 0;
   bool parsed = Int32.TryParse("123", out i);
   ```

There is also the possibility to use TryParseExact, where a certain pattern can be parsed. It can be useful in certain cases.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule of thumb, you should be avoiding the `Convert` class altogether. There are reasons to use it (e.g, you do not know the source type), but if you already know your source type is a `string` then `Parse` (or, more correctly, `TryParse`) is always the right method to use.

As for type converters, they are more often than not used when a framework (such as WPF) uses reflection to determine the right sort of type converter.

You forgot another way of converting, that is the direct cast. Take this code for example

```
object i = 1;
int myInt = (int)i;
```

This is a bit of a contrived example, but I already know that `i` is an int, its just that its boxed into an `object`. In this case I do not need to convert `i`, I just need to directly cast it to the type which I know it already is.

Comment: Isn't direct casting only possible when the object is in fact that type already? Like in your example, but converting a string into a number wouldn't work at al.

Comment: @Joachim - Absolutely, I added it for posterity as its one that usually gets confused with Converting.

Comment: @Jamiec, can you please provide reasoning behind your stmt "As a general rule of thumb, you should avoid the Convert class"?  I'd like to see some reasoning, blog posts, etc. to defend the statement.  Thanks.

Comment: @DaveBlack - or, you could go and do your own research? To put it bluntly, `Convert` is the proverbial sledgehammer when often what you need is a pin hammer (again, proverbially speaking, `int.Parse` perhaps). Have a look at the decompiled source for `Convert.ChangeType` and see just how many things it tries. often you will know exactly what conversion method to use directly without this "one size fits all" approach.

Comment: I've already done the research and found nothing that raises a red flag (which is why I asked the reason for your strong opinion to avoid it). Performance is close enough in microseconds to have no difference of any consequence (by using Vance Morrison's MeasureIt app - former CLR Performance Architect). If the class is there and there's no sensible reason to not use it, then I'd say do it. I'm all for having knowledge of what the Framework and runtime do.  However, in this case, it's nothing more than an academic exercise to look at Convert.ChangeType()

Comment: (cont'd) there's something to be said about have a Framework that just does things for you and abstracts away the implementation details.  Contrary to popular belief, working with the Type system in .NET 4.5 is blazingly fast as the reflection engine was basically re-written. I've done plenty of perf testing around it and it is orders of magnitude faster than what it was in previous versions of the Framework.  So, I'd ask what's wrong with a "one-size fits all" soln if it 1. performs just as well 2. is more maintainable instead of having multiple ways of type conversion spread across your app?

Comment: (cont'd) and 3. it works just as well.  I should add that all the perf testing was done with MeasureIt instead of the typical (and often inaccurate) Linqpad /Stopwatch tests that most use for perf measurement.

Answer (score 3):

Just found out a case that `TypeConvert.ConvertFrom(object)` throws exception. 
If you want to convert an Integer 0/1 to a Boolean.  You will get exception using `TypeConvert.ConvertFrom(1)` or `(0)`.  In this case, `Convert.ChangeType(1, System.Boolean)` works.

Comment: Similarly, `TypeConvert.ConvertFrom()` throws an exception converting Int64 to Int32 regardless of the value, whereas `Convert.ChangeType()` succeeds as long as the value doesn't overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I pretty much always use the int/double/etc.Parse() methods, when I'm certain it's a number. In any case of doubt, I us the .TryParse() methods, as an all-in-one solution including parsing and checking. I have this feeling that checking and parsing combined is slightly more performant than doing them separately.

TypeConverter is probably only useful when you don't really know the types at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Another late answer. I have an application where I was using some code that looks like this:

`var finalValue = Convert.ChangeType(sourceValue, targetProperty.PropertyType);`

`sourceValue` would be a `string` representation of what I wanted which normally would be a `primitive` under a `wrapper class`. This way would work with regular data types. Even with entire classes. However, one day I stupidly decided to change the datatype of a property that was a `double` to a nullable one `double?` guess what? boom!

> invalid cast from string to nullable double

This is the perfect scenario where you should use the `TypeConverter`  class as follows:

```
void Main()
{
    var ss = new[] {"2.01", "3.99", ""};
    var conv = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(A).GetProperties().First().PropertyType);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", ss.Select(s => conv.ConvertFrom(s))));
}

class A {
    public double? b {get; set;}
}

//2.01,3.99,
```