# How to call some method via Reflection without any parameters and any return values?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

How to call some method via Reflection without any parameters and any return values?

Here is MSDN [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
// Define a class with a generic method.
public class Example
{
    public static void Generic<T>()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\r\nHere it is: {0}", "DONE");
    }
}
```

What should be within typeof(???) then?

```
MethodInfo miConstructed = mi.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(???));
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Perhaps any type would work. Have you tried using, say, string?

Comment: check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569249/methodinfo-invoke-with-out-parameter

Comment: Define "doesn't work" ... ? what happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were invoking that through C#, you would need to supply a type, for example:

```
Example.Generic<int>();
```

that requirement does not change; simply, that line would become:

```
mi.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int)).Invoke(null, null);
```

For a complete, working illustration:

```
class Example
{
    public static void Generic<T>()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("\r\nHere it is: {0}", "DONE");
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        var mi = typeof (Example).GetMethod("Generic");
        mi.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int)).Invoke(null, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Before being able to invoke a generic method you need to specify its generic argument(s). So you pass the type you want to be used as generic argument:

```
public class Example
{
    public static void Generic<T>()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The type of T is: {0}", typeof(T));
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var mi = typeof(Example).GetMethod("Generic");
        MethodInfo miConstructed = mi.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));
        miConstructed.Invoke(null, null);
    }
}
```

which should print:

```
The type of T is: System.String
```