# How to do a generic cast using reflection and out parameter

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a big dictionary of (string, object). The values in the dictionary are of different types. Only at run time I can find the exact type of the values in the dictionary of (string, int)  or (string, string). At run time I have to assign the values in the dictionary to their corresponding strongly typed objects. This is the simplified problem.
I'm trying to use a typed class that does the cast.
I have this code that does not work:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var values = new Dictionary<string, object> 
    { 
        { "123", "test"},
        {"12", 123}
    };
    var result = new Dictionary<string, object> ();

    Type dict = values.GetType();
    Type typedCast = typeof(TypedClass<>).MakeGenericType(new [] { dict });
    MethodInfo method = typedCast.GetMethod("GetTypedValue", 
        BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, 
        null, 
        new[]
            {
                  typeof(object), 
                  typeof(object).MakeByRefType()
            },
        null);

    method.Invoke(null, new[]{values, result});
}

public class TypedClass<T>
{
    public static void GetTypedValue(object value, out object obj)
    {
        obj = (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Inside the GetTypedValue method I see the obj value with the correct type, but outside this method the out variable has no values. Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Is your intent that given a `Dictionary<string, object>` populated with a combination of `string` and `int` values, to produce two dictionaries, one `<string, string>` and the other `<string, int>` populated with the corresponding values matched by type?  So from your sample code, you'd have a result of one dictionary containing `{"123", "test"}` and a second dictionary containing `{"12", 123}`?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569249/methodinfo-invoke-with-out-parameter. You need to store the array passed to method.Invoke in a variable and retrieve the result from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
method.Invoke(null, new[]{values, result});
```

with

```
var invokeArgs = new[]{values, result};
method.Invoke(null, invokeArgs);
//here you can check the invokeArgs[1] for the actual result of the conversion
```

In any case, I'm not sure why you would want to convert the type of a Dictionary to another Dictionary, because that's what your code seems to do...

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem. I'm trying to handle around 100 different types of dictionaries in a generic way, but returning the result as a typed result to be stored in its old variable.

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of your out object obj argument to out T obj