# How can I call a method from a Template?

Tags: c#, templates, generics, data-structures, struct

I have this C# WinForms code in which I have several different `structs`, that all function in the same way. So instead of writing individual functions for adding or removing items, I'm trying to use Templates instead.

For example, here is one `struct` and the corresponding `List<>` I'm using to store its `objects`:

```
public struct Alias
{
    public string alias;
    public string aliasSource;

    public static bool IsValid(...); //This function exists in all the structs
};

List<Alias> aliases;
```

This the function used from the outside, to add Aliases:

```
public void AddAlias(Alias iAlias)
{
    AddGenericStructItem<Alias>(iAlias, aliases);
}
```

And this is the actual function doing the addition:

```
private void AddGenericStructItem<T>(T genericStructItem, List<T> genericList)
{
    string outputError;
    if (T.IsValid(genericStructItem, out outputError)) //< -- Problem in the 'T' being used in the far left
    {
        if (genericList.Contains(genericStructItem))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR 82ha5jb :: Item already exists");
        }
        else
        {
            genericList.Add(genericStructItem);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(outputError);
    }
}
```

The problem occurs in the `T.IsValid...` part. The compiler gives me the following error on the `T`:

```
'T' is a 'type parameter', which is not valid in the given context
```

Is there any way around this?  All my `structs` have an `IsValid` function in them with the same setup, so it would seem silly to repeatedly write the same code, in case I don't use templates here...

Comment: C# generics are _significantly_ different from templates in C++, although the syntax looks similar.

Comment: I'm interested in why IsValid() is static. I would expect a method called IsValid() to require access to the object.

Comment: Yes thats one way to look at it I guess. The way I use it though is when I need to verify the inputs themselves (based on which the struct instance is later created), so the validation needs to happen beforehand, which is why a static method was needed in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use constraints to tell the compiler that a static method will exist on your object. If it really needs to be static, you'll need to use reflection to call the method:

```
var methodInfo = typeof(T).GetMethod("IsValid", BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.Public);
if (methodInfo != null)
{
    object[] parameters = new object[] { genericStructItem, null };
    if ((bool)methodInfo.Invoke(null, parameters))
    {
        // It's valid!
    }
    else
    {
        string error = (string)parameters[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what you put inside `(...)` ? Here's the complete line I'm using: `var isValid = (bool)methodInfo.Invoke(genericStructItem, out outputError);`, but this gives me the error: `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(object, object[])' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: I'll update my code. Also, this post does a very good job explaining static method calls via reflection with an out parameter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569249/methodinfo-invoke-with-out-parameter

Comment: Not sure how that scenario fits mine. I figured out what I need to put in place of `object, object []`, but then my problem is the that the `out` parameter doesn't work (just like the issue in the thread you pointed to). However, the solution on that page uses a C# defined function to use TryParse (i.e. `GetTryParseMethodInfo()`), which I cannot do because `IsValid` in my own function.

Comment: The code in my answer has been updated to fit your scenario. It should work.

Comment: Just seen the code. Seems to be okay, but I think you've nulled the `out` parameter. Isn't it possible to get the `out` part as well somehow ?

Comment: A useful optimization when using this technique is to create a static generic class with a static field to cache the information retrieved via Reflection.  Using Reflection to perform a look-up every time you need to call a method may be slow, but caching the result with a static generic class can speed things up considerably.  Rather than testing whether the delegate has initialized, one can have the class statically initialize it to a member which will perform the lookup, cache the delegate, and invoke it.

Comment: @itsme86, your solution seems to be working. The error is also showing when the input is invalid. How does it work though, since you're passing `null` in place of where the out parameter needs to go ? @supercat, I'll look into that, Thanks !

Comment: @Ahmad The error should _only_ show when the input is invalid, assuming IsValid() is returning `true` when the input is valid. I'd have to see what your IsValid() method looks like to help you any further.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. The only option is defining `where` constraint for your generic parameter to be of some interface or base class type. But you can't do this neither with structs nor with static members. If you change your structs to classes, then you can do following:

```
public interface IValidatable
{
   bool IsValid(out outputError);
}

public class Alias : IValidatable
{
    public string alias;
    public string aliasSource;

    public bool IsValid(out outputError) { ... };
};
```

Now you can apply constraint:

```
private void AddValidatableItem<T>(T item, List<T> list)
   where T : IValidatable
{
    string outputError;
    if (!item.IsValid(out outputError))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(outputError);
        return;
    }

    if (list.Contains(item))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR 82ha5jb :: Item already exists");
        return;
    }

    list.Add(item);       
}
```

BTW you can take advantage of C# extension methods and make this method an extension of validatable items list:

```
public static void AddValidatableItem<T>(this List<T> list, T item)
    where T : IValidatable
```

This will allow you to call method on list:

```
aliases.AddValidatableItem(newAlias);
```

Comment: This is great for non-static methods, but doesn't apply to static methods.

Comment: @itsme86 pleas read first paragraph of my answer more carefully

Answer (score 0):

C# generics are *significantly* different from templates in C++, although the syntax looks similar.

When you say

```
T.IsValid(genericStructItem, out outputError);
```

it sounds like you are expecting the compiler to substitute `T` with `Alias` to give you

```
Alias.IsValid(genericStructItem, out outputError);
```

which is not how generics work.  You need to find another way to call `IsValid`, such as reflection or adding a common interface to your structs.

Also I would *strongly* consider using classes instead of structs.  I don't know your reasons for choosing structs but in general there are several reasons *not* to use structs, especially if they need to be mutable.