# How to invoke without parameters method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one class in which public method without input parameter.

```
 public partial class MyClass: System.Web.UI.MasterPage
   {

      public void HelloWorld() { 
       Console.WriteLine("Hello World "); 
      } 
    }
```

I want to invoke `HelloWorld()`  method into my another class

```
public partial class ProductType_Showpt : System.Web.UI.Page
{
     protected void ChkChanged_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          MyClass master =(MyClass) this.Master;   
          master.GetType().GetMethod("HelloWorld").Invoke(null, null);
    }
}
```

but it's throw this exception

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569249/methodinfo-invoke-with-out-parameter

Comment: is there a reason to use reflection to call the method?

Comment: I try to call directly master.Helloworld() but it's not search so I need to call Invoke method.

Answer (score 10):

Here you haven't use the class as first parameter in `Invoke` ie, you have to apply code as below.

```
MyClass master= new MyClass();  
master.GetType().GetMethod("HelloWorld").Invoke(objMyClass, null);
```

Now there may be another possibility of throwing error if you have another method with some parameters(Overloaded method). In such case, you have to write code specifying you need to invoke the method which doesn't have parameters.

```
MyClass master= new MyClass();  
MethodInfo mInfo = master.GetType().GetMethods().FirstOrDefault
                (method => method.Name == "HelloWorld"
                && method.GetParameters().Count() == 0);
mInfo.Invoke(objMyClass, null);
```

Now if you class instance is not known in advance you can use the following code. Use [Fully Qualified Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) inside `Type.GetType`

```
Type type = Type.GetType("YourNamespace.MyClass");
object objMyClass = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
MethodInfo mInfo = objMyClass.GetType().GetMethods().FirstOrDefault
                   (method => method.Name == "HelloWorld"
                    && method.GetParameters().Count() == 0);
mInfo.Invoke(objMyClass, null);
```

If your class instance is unknown in advance, and is in another assembly, `Type.GetType` may return null. In such case, for the above code, instead of `Type.GetType`, call the below method

```
public Type GetTheType(string strFullyQualifiedName)
{
    Type type = Type.GetType(strFullyQualifiedName);
    if (type != null)
        return type;
    foreach (var asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    {
        type = asm.GetType(strFullyQualifiedName);
        if (type != null)
           return type;
    }
    return null;
}
```

And call like

```
Type type = GetTheType("YourNamespace.MyClass");
```

Answer (score 7):

I believe your `Invoke` method shouldn't take `null` parameter as a first one.

```
MyClass yourclass = new MyClass();    
MyClass.GetType().GetMethod("HelloWorld").Invoke(yourclass , null);
```

For first parameters from [`MethodBase.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx)

> The object on which to invoke the method or constructor. If a method
>   is static, this argument is ignored. If a constructor is static, this
>   argument must be **null** or an instance of the class that defines the
>   constructor.

Comment: Hello Soner : I update the code with real implementation. I try to call master page method with the master.Helloworld() but it's not call so I try with invoke method. But your logic also throw same error.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to invoke method on null instead of instance of object, you can invoke instance method on instance of class not on null. pass instance of your class in first parameter of `HelloWorld` method.

```
MyClass myClassObject = new MyClass();    
MyClass.GetType().GetMethod("HelloWorld").Invoke(myClassObject, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify an instance to execute the method on:

```
MyClass myClassInstance = new MyClass();
MyClass.GetType().GetMethod("HelloWorld").Invoke(myClassInstance, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either maark the `HelloWorld()` method as `static` or pass a `MyClass` instance as the first parameter to the `Invoke` method (as previous answers said).