# Passing "params" as input with C#

Tags: c#

I have a function that looks like:

```
FuncA(int num, object[] x)
```

And a function that this function will be using that's written in this sort of way:

```
FuncB(string s, object x1)
FuncB(string s, object x1, object x2)
...
```

Such that function B has many overloads of this form (32 actually) and is a given function (I can't access it).

I would like to call FuncB in FuncA such that I'm calling the right overload based on the length of the input object.

Is there a clever way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: The input of FuncA can be: params object[] x instead. I don't see how that helps. The issue is that the given FuncB is written in this strange way.

Comment: the "quickest" solution is to use reflection but I wouldn't recommend doing that if performance is important for you

Comment: 32 overloads for the same function is a bit excessive, particularly since they're all the same type.  Is there any particular reason you need to do this that can't be done via passing an array/List in?

Comment: What's the name of the library with these 32 overloads?

Comment: It's mlapp, a MATLAB dll. If your want to run MATLAB functions from c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind using reflections, you should be able to do that with this kind of code:

```
int FuncA(int num, object[] x)
{
    if (x.Length == 0 || x.Length > 32) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    IEnumerable<Type> types = new[] { typeof(string) }.Concat(x.Select(i => typeof(object)));
    MethodInfo info = typeof(FuncBClass).GetMethod("FuncB", types.ToArray());
    IEnumerable<object> parameters = new[] { "Some string" }.Concat(x);
    object result = info.Invoke(null /* ignored if the method is static */, parameters.ToArray());
    return (int)result;
}
```

Basically here's what it does:

- Get a `IEnumerable<Type>` with the types of the target method overload (FuncB has a string and then n objects x1...xn)
- Get the `MethodInfo` object that represents the target overload to use
- Get a `IEnumerable<object>` with the parameters to pass to that method overload, so your string and then the list of objects
- Invoke the method with those parameters and cast its result

*Notes*:

- I assumed there's a `FuncBClass` class that contains all those methods you need
- I passed `null` to the `Invoke` method as I assumed those methods were static. If they're not, you might need to adjust that line and create an instance of their class to pass to the `Invoke` method for it to work correctly

**Edit**: here's an example if one of the `FuncB` parameters is an `out` parameter, as suggested by the OP. I'm assuming the parameter is the first one in the list of x1..xn numbers here, the general idea is the same for every possible position anyways (or if the `out` is the string too).

```
int FuncA(int num, object[] x)
{
    if (x.Length == 0 || x.Length > 32) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    IEnumerable<Type> types = new[] { typeof(string) }.Concat(x.Select(i => typeof(object)));
    MethodInfo info = typeof(int).GetMethod("FuncB", types.ToArray());
    object[] parameters = new[] { "Some string", null /* the out parameter */ }.Concat(x.Skip(1)).ToArray();
    info.Invoke(null /* ignored if the method is static */, parameters);
    return (int)parameters[1]; // Get the out parameter value and cast it
}
```

Comment: One of the parameters in an out parameter. Anyway to deal with that?

Comment: @AsaridBeck91 for out parameters, just pass null in that position in the parameters array, and then get that object from the array after calling Invoke. That null object will be replaced by the value just like when using an out parameter. See here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569249/methodinfo-invoke-with-out-parameter

Comment: @AsaridBeck91 I've updated my answer with an example in case one of the parameters is marked as out, please mark it as correct if that was the solution to your question :)

Answer (score 3):

If all `FuncB` methods are part of the same class, you could use the [`Type.GetMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hy0h0z1(v=vs.110).aspx) overload which accepts a `Type[]` parameter containing exact types for each parameter.

On the other hand, if each method is supplied from elsewhere, you can store them in an array or a dictionary (i.e. map "number of parameters" to each concrete method):

```
map[1] = (object[] x) => FuncB(x[0]);
map[2] = (object[] x) => FuncB(x[0], x[1]);
```

I am wondering, however, if your design is right, and perhaps could be implemented in a better way altogether.

Comment: They are from the same class. In that case even if I get the right overload, how would I call it in a length dependent way?

Comment: @AsaridBeck91: hi, sorry I didn't see your comment earlier. I can see that the answer below shows how to call it (i.e. simply call `MethodInfo.Invoke` with an array of parameters). If performance is your concern, you can use [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.createdelegate.aspx) to create a plain delegate from that method info, and then put it into a dictionary/array to get fast runtime dispatch for each number of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a pretty isolated case, and you need it to be fastish, I'd probably byte the bullet and use a switch on the length instead of using reflection (which would be more concise code, but slower)

so

```
switch(num)
{
  case 1: return FuncB(x[0]); 
  case 2: return FuncB(x[0], x[1]); 
  etc
```

while ugly, it will be reasonably quick.

If this is a common pattern in the library, I'd probably look at using some code generation to create an assembly with adapters.  Or perhaps someone has already made a wrapper library.

Comment: That's what I'll do. Thanks.