# Syntax Error when invoking method from dll using "out" arguments

Tags: c#, dll, syntax-error, invoke, out

I'm trying to call a method from a dll fetched within the code.
The foreign method to call:

```
private bool someMethod(out string errMsg)
    {
      //Error message is assigned
      //Some more code
      return aBoolean;
    }
```

When I call the method with the following code:

```
string errorMessage;  
someMethod.Invoke(activator, new object[] {out errorMessage});
```

I get the following error for "out errorMessage":
Syntax error, ',' expected -- ',' or '}' expected

The method itself is correctly called when I ignore the out prefix, and the activator is assigned correctly according to the tests I have made

What's going on here?

Comment: Target Framework is 4.0. I tried 4.5, no dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why

```
string errorMessage;  
someMethod.Invoke(activator, new object[] {out errorMessage});
```

won't compile is two-fold.

1. `out` must be specified against a parameter, not against a variable that happens to be being used to *initialise* a parameter.
2. The `Invoke` method does not take an out parameter.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569249/methodinfo-invoke-with-out-parameter) could be used to solve your problem, rather than trying to use `out`.